# WebView2 - Selecting text and copying to clipboard

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, webview2

With the `CHtmlView` class I was able to select all the text and copy to the clipboard like this:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::CopyToClipboard()
{
    ExecWB(OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, nullptr, nullptr);
}

void CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::SelectAll()
{
    ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

I am trying to find out how to do the same with the new WebView2 API.

---

### Update

The WebView2 control supports by design:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the content.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the selected text to the clipboard.

I found a VB.NET solution to programatically copy all the page to the clipboard:

```
Sub Async GetText()
  v = Await wv.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.innerText")
End Sub
```

But I am using Visual C++ and I do not see this method exposed. Also, I am not sure it is what I want because I do not want to copy as plain text data but HTML data (suitable for pasting in Word) like with the hotkeys. I have made a [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1474) issue for this too.

---

### Update

So I have now tried this code but it does not appear to do anything:

```
void CWebBrowser::CopyToClipboard()
{
    if (m_pImpl->m_webView != nullptr)
    {
        m_pImpl->m_webView->ExecuteScript(_T("document.body.innerText"), nullptr);

    }
}
```

---

### Update

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/win32-api-conventions) it states:

> Alternately, for `ICoreWebView2::ExecuteScript`, you provide an instance that has an `Invoke` method that provides you with the success or failure code of the `ExecuteScript` request. Also provide the second parameter that is the `JSON` of the result of running the script.

Trying to find example.

---

### Update

I now understand that I need to do something like this:

```
void CWebBrowser::CopyToClipboard()
{
    if (m_pImpl->m_webView != nullptr)
    {
        m_pImpl->m_webView->ExecuteScript(L"document.body.innerText",
            Callback<ICoreWebView2ExecuteScriptCompletedHandler>(
                [](HRESULT error, PCWSTR result) -> HRESULT
                {
                    if (error != S_OK) {
                        ShowFailure(error, L"ExecuteScript failed");
                    }
                    SetClipboardText(result);
                    AfxMessageBox(L"HTML copied to clipboard!", MB_OK);
                    return S_OK;
                }).Get());


    }
}
```

The variable `result` has the contents of the HTML page. But it does not like my call to `SetClipboardText` now. This is the error:

[image]

This is the function:

```
void CWebBrowser::SetClipboardText(CString strText)
{
    BYTE* pbyText;
    TCHAR* pcBuffer;
    HANDLE  hText;
    UINT    uLength;

    //USES_CONVERSION ;

    if (::OpenClipboard(nullptr))
    {
        // Empty it of all data first.
        ::EmptyClipboard();

        // Replace previous text contents.
        uLength = strText.GetLength();
        //pcBuffer = T2A( (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)strText);
        pcBuffer = strText.GetBuffer(uLength);
        if (pcBuffer != nullptr)
        {
            hText = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, (uLength + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
            if (hText != nullptr)
            {
                pbyText = (BYTE*)::GlobalLock(hText);
                if (pbyText != nullptr)
                {
                    // Deliberately not _tcscpy().
                    //strcpy_s( (char *)pbyText, uLength+1, pcBuffer);
                    _tcscpy_s((TCHAR*)pbyText, uLength + 1, pcBuffer);
                    ::GlobalUnlock(hText);

                    ::SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hText);

                    // Don't free this memory, clipboard owns it now.
                }
            }
        }
        ::CloseClipboard();

        strText.ReleaseBuffer(uLength);
    }
}
```

This is the only way I know (to date) to copy to clipboard. So I have two issues here:

1. It will not let me use this function.
2. I expect it will copy just text (`CF_UNICODETEXT`) and I don't know if that is sufficient for pasting the data as HTML into Word?

Concerning issue 1, I needed to make the method `static`. Then it compiled and copied the information to the clipboard.

Concerning issue 2, as expected, the pasted data was stripped HTML and I was left with just the text. And the new line characters were displayed as `"\n"` in the text. It was one huge paragraph. So I do indeed need the `CF_HTML` format.

It is a pity that the `WebView2` does not expose the **copy to clipboard** feature that it already has functional.

---

### Update

This is the [clipboard method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/add-html-code-clipboard) that I found on the internet for `CF_HTML`:

```
// CopyHtml() - Copies given HTML to the clipboard.
// The HTML/BODY blanket is provided, so you only need to
// call it like CopyHtml("<b>This is a test</b>");
void CopyHTML(char* html)
{
    // Create temporary buffer for HTML header...
    char* buf = new char[400 + strlen(html)];
    if (!buf) return;

    // Get clipboard id for HTML format...
    static int cfid = 0;
    if (!cfid) cfid = RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format");

    // Create a template string for the HTML header...
    strcpy(buf,
        "Version:0.9\r\n"
        "StartHTML:00000000\r\n"
        "EndHTML:00000000\r\n"
        "StartFragment:00000000\r\n"
        "EndFragment:00000000\r\n"
        "<html><body>\r\n"
        "<!--StartFragment -->\r\n");

    // Append the HTML...
    strcat(buf, html);
    strcat(buf, "\r\n");
    // Finish up the HTML format...
    strcat(buf,
        "<!--EndFragment-->\r\n"
        "</body>\r\n"
        "</html>");

    // Now go back, calculate all the lengths, and write out the
    // necessary header information. Note, wsprintf() truncates the
    // string when you overwrite it so you follow up with code to replace
    // the 0 appended at the end with a '\r'...
    char* ptr = strstr(buf, "StartHTML");
    wsprintf(ptr + 10, "%08u", strstr(buf, "<html>") - buf);
    *(ptr + 10 + 8) = '\r';

    ptr = strstr(buf, "EndHTML");
    wsprintf(ptr + 8, "%08u", strlen(buf));
    *(ptr + 8 + 8) = '\r';

    ptr = strstr(buf, "StartFragment");
    wsprintf(ptr + 14, "%08u", strstr(buf, "<!--StartFrag") - buf);
    *(ptr + 14 + 8) = '\r';

    ptr = strstr(buf, "EndFragment");
    wsprintf(ptr + 12, "%08u", strstr(buf, "<!--EndFrag") - buf);
    *(ptr + 12 + 8) = '\r';

    // Now you have everything in place ready to put on the clipboard.
    // Open the clipboard...
    if (OpenClipboard(0))
    {
        // Empty what's in there...
        EmptyClipboard();

        // Allocate global memory for transfer...
        HGLOBAL hText = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, strlen(buf) + 4);

        // Put your string in the global memory...
        char* ptr = (char*)GlobalLock(hText);
        strcpy(ptr, buf);
        GlobalUnlock(hText);

        ::SetClipboardData(cfid, hText);

        CloseClipboard();
        // Free memory...
        GlobalFree(hText);
    }
    // Clean up...
    delete[] buf;
}
```

But it is not compatible with the `PCWSTR` variable.

---

### Update

I have now realised after doing debugging that `ExecuteScript` does return the actual `HTML` data if I use `document.body.innerText`. The resulting string is just text with `\n` characters for the new lines. It is not in `HTML` format. So I am back to square one.

Comment: `ExecuteScript` returns the text, all you have to do is copy it to the clipboard (I'm not a C++ guy). Search here on SO how to do that.

Comment: @PoulBak But the return value of `ExecuteScript` is a `HRESULT` value.

Comment: To convert `PCWSRT` to `UTF-8` - would this work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am showing this as an alternative because the current approach does not include the actual HTML content. The information I found on the internet was misleading about using `document.body.innerText`.

One solution to this is to use the `document.execCommand()` route. I added the following methods to my browser class:

```
void CWebBrowser::SelectAll()
{
    if (m_pImpl->m_webView != nullptr)
    {
        m_pImpl->m_webView->ExecuteScript(L"document.execCommand(\"SelectAll\")", nullptr);
    }
}


void CWebBrowser::CopyToClipboard2()
{
    if (m_pImpl->m_webView != nullptr)
    {
        m_pImpl->m_webView->ExecuteScript(L"document.execCommand(\"Copy\")", nullptr);
    }
}
```

Then I added the following button handlers to my dialog to test:

```
void CMFCTestWebView2Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonSelectAll()
{
    if (m_pWebBrowser != nullptr)
    {
        m_pWebBrowser->SelectAll();
    }
}


void CMFCTestWebView2Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonCopyToClipboard()
{
    if (m_pWebBrowser != nullptr)
    {
        m_pWebBrowser->CopyToClipboard2();
    }
}
```

This does work and appears to be the simplest solution for now. I see references to the [`Clipboard API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) as an alternative but I am not sure yet how to implement that approach.

My only concern with `execCommand` is that I have seen it documented as **deprecated**.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ICoreWebView2::ExecuteScript`.

Comment: You have to choose the correct clipboard format.
You can parse the HTML and transfer it to some text format.
Else choose CF_HTML (you find enough in the web)

Comment: See my question update. I found code to copy char * but not PCWSTR. It fails.